# In what situation does fgets() get stuck?

Tags: c, linux, fgets

```
printf("ok before fgets\n");
while ( (fgets(buff, sizeof(buff), fi)) != NULL)
{
    printf("ok after");
    if(write(connfd,buff,strlen(buff)) != strlen(buff))
    {
        printf("write() failed\n");
        close(connfd);
        exit(1);
    }
}
```

Here's the code. The code prints "ok before fgets" but it never prints "ok after". I wonder what is the problem.

In case that the information is not enough, I am writing a network communication program. And as soon as the client program is killed, this program is free from stuck and prints out several "ok after". It seems related to the network, but how can fgets() a local file related to the network? I am actually trying to send this file to the remote client, but it seems the bug happens before sending.

---

*After discussion in chat, it became clear that the problem was not `fgets()` at all, but the network code.  The diagnostic message in the loop has no newline, so the diagnostic output was not appearing when produced.*

---

Thanks to  [Jonathan Leffler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15168/jonathan-leffler), the problem is solved. The printf("ok after"); information did not appear because no newline is printed out. So by adding a newline: printf(ok after\n); we can see that the "ok after" is printed out.

Comment: Did you successfully open `fi`? How big is `buff`?

Comment: @dmckee, how to check if I successfully opened it? It is not NULL though. buff is big enough to hold the entire file.

Comment: Do you have a `printf()` call after the body of the loop?  Could it be that the file is empty?  Is there any chance that you're opening some sort of special file, such as a FIFO?  If so, are you opening it for reading and writing — that would hang `fgets()` in perpetuity.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, I've edited the problem. It is stuck in the loop, since "ok after" is printed out later. I later opened this file and it is non-empty. What is FIFO? I opened the file by FILE* fi = fopen(fileName, "r");

Comment: A FIFO is also called a named pipe.  Let's assume that it is not germane to your problem (but you could check by looking at the file with `ls -l`; if the permissions field starts `p` instead of `-`, you have a FIFO).

Comment: When you're printing debugging information, *always* end the message with a newline `\n`; the message won't appear timely if you don't.  Also consider writing debug information to `stderr` instead of `stdout`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, it is -rw-r--r--

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18502/discussion-between-jonathan-leffler-and-user1214321)

Answer (score 2):

there are 2 possibilities:

- there was an error in fgets() and the while loop is never entered, since it returned NULL.

or

- fgets is waiting for sizeof(buff) character, a new line or EOF:

> The fgets() function shall read bytes from stream into the array
>   pointed to by s, until n-1 bytes are read, or a <newline> is read and
>   transferred to s, or an end-of-file condition is encountered. The
>   string is then terminated with a null byte.

http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904875/functions/fgets.html

Since you say it is stuck, it indicates the 2nd option.

cheers

Comment: Nice catch on the "stuck" thing, though OP says the buffer is big enough to read the whole file, so now I am confused.

Comment: @dmckee I've added some information. The fi is a local file. Since it is not null, I suppose I have opened it.

Answer (score -1):

From the man page for `fgets` (the one on my Mac OS 10.5 box):

> The fgets() and gets() functions do not distinguish between end-of-file and
>        error; callers must use feof(3) and ferror(3) to determine which
>        occurred.

so at this point you haven't given us (or yourself) enough data to diagnose the problem.

---

Note that the `(3)` in there is just an indication of what section of the unix manual you would consult, and has nothing to do with the parameters to those functions.